# How do I go create a button from Formx.vb to Formx.vb [Design]

Tags: vb.net, button, class-design

My question is in fact this: I know how to manipulate the code from a button (by double clicking it) from the design tab but how do I create a button from the code section wich will appear in the design tab? If I simply put the code for a new button it will do nothing:
Private Sub Button1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.click
If you have the answer please help me. 
With great respect for your work, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private btnAdd As New Button()
```

Have a look at [How to programmatically add controls to Windows Forms](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308433)

Comment: I must mention the fact that I am currently using Visual Studio 2010. When I added the code you said the button did not show in the design tab. I tried to debug it and it still didn't show me no button. I read your link and did what it said but it still didn't work.

Comment: Most of the commands that the link recommanded aren't recognized by my version of VB

Comment: Any button you add programmatically will only show when the application is run.

Answer (score 0):

*Why don't you want to use the designer?*

There is a hidden file named **Formx.Designer.vb** in your project. If you click the **Show All Files** button in the **Solution Explorer** tool pane, you'll see it collapsed in the **Formx.vb** file.

This file ultimately controls what the designer shows. You can edit it by hand but you risk the problem of creating code that the designer cannot read and when you use the designer after hand-editing the file, it may throw away your changes.

Here is some code that creates a button and hooks the click event. It runs on `form.load` but you can do it wherever you want.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Button2 As Button

    Button2 = New Button()
    Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(80, 80)
    Button2.Name = "Button2"
    Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Button2.TabIndex = 0
    Button2.Text = "Button2"
    Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True

    AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf MyButton_Click

    Controls.Add(Button2)
End Sub

Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("yes")
End Sub
```